# Move a project to Bitbucket

Tags: php, git, codeigniter, bitbucket

I already looking for a few hours to find the solution to a problem.So I have a project(my blog),create in Code Igniter,I have a mini server and he is where.I created an account on the bit bucket.org,I installed mingw and I want to work with git 
to improve project.What are the steps that need to follow,help me please

Answer (score 1):

Create a repository -> Create your project -> Setup Git on your local machine -> Push your project into your Git Repository -> Push/Pull further changes